# mysql date insert null

Tags: php, mysql, дата, null

Перепробовал уже все варианты со всех сайтов, даже индийских. Нужно писать в поле с датой  (mag_unban_date) значение null, а пишется 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Пробовал и пустое поле, и в кавычках, и присваивать null непосредственно перед отправкой. Переменная php null принимает, а в бд пишутся нули. В бд по умолчанию null настроен.

```
$query ="INSERT INTO `mag_bans`(`mag_steam_id`, `mag_admin_id`,`mag_date`, `mag_unban_date`, `mag_reason`) VALUES ('$mag_steam_id','$mag_admin_id', '$mag_date','$mag_unban_date','$mag_reason') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `mag_admin_id`='$mag_admin_id', `mag_date` = '$mag_date', `mag_unban_date` = '$mag_unban_date', `mag_reason` = '$mag_reason'";
```

UPD:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mag_bans ( 
    mag_bid bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    mag_steam_id varchar(80) NOT NULL, 
    mag_admin_id varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL, 
    mag_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    mag_unban_date timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
    mag_reason varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (mag_bid), 
    UNIQUE KEY mag_steam_id (mag_steam_id) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=713 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

UPD: Получилось. Вместо проверки на null замутил проверку на пустую строку и пишу в переменную пустую строку. Огромное спасибо)

Comment: Покажите `SHOW CREATE TABLE mag_bans;` и `SELECT SESSION sql_mode;`.

Comment: В показанном тексте запроса нельзя передать NULL - передастся строка `'NULL'`, которая будет преобразована в нулевую дату. Так что `.. VALUES ( .. , NULLIF('$date_value', 'NULL') , ..`

Comment: Попробовал. Все равно нули пишет

Comment: А где сведения об SQL mode?

Comment: @Akina не совсем понял, куда вводить этот запрос. При вводе в phpmyadmin выдает ошибку синтаксиса.

Comment: Тогда так: `SELECT @@sql_mode;`. Ну и просто почитайте про опциональные переменные... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-option-variable-reference.html